# Apply class randomly to the list items for every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items in which I have animation.. In this I need to change class of list items in a circular basis for every 5 seconds.

I have 5 list-items, at 1st none of them will have class.. once the page open classes has to be assigned to them like "card0", "card1", "card2", "card3", "card4" respectively.. and then every 5 seconds it has to interchanged in circular

```html
<div class="changelog">

    <ul class="entries">
        <li class="card0" style="transform: translateY(122px) scale(1.07);">
            <p class="meta">
                <strong>Connect</strong>
                <span>August 1</span>
            </p>
            <p>Platforms can now export connected account information as a CSV from the Dashboard.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="card1" style="transform: translateY(152px) scale(1);">
            <p class="meta">
                <strong>Terminal</strong>
                <span>July 30</span>
            </p>
            <p>You can now use WiFi to connect a P400 card reader to your point of sale application.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="card2" style="transform: translateY(182px) scale(0.934579);">
            <p class="meta">
                <strong>Connect</strong>
                <span>July 29</span>
            </p>
            <p>Express accounts now support 5 new languages (German, Italian, Japanese, Spanish, and Simplified Chinese) for the onboarding flow, dashboard, emails, and text messages.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="card3" style="transform: translateY(212px) scale(0.873439);">
            <p class="meta">
                <strong>Radar</strong>
                <span>July 22</span>
            </p>
            <p>Set rules with the new <code>is_off_session</code> attribute, which detects if a customer was charged anytime after they initially completed the checkout&nbsp;flow.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="card4" style="transform: translateY(272px) scale(0.816298);">
            <p class="meta">
                <strong>Mobile</strong>
                <span>July 19</span>
            </p>
            <p>Our updated mobile SDKs now support in-app 3D Secure 2 authentication, letting you customize the appearance of the authentication&nbsp;UI.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Use `setInterval` and `Math.random`.

Comment: no i didn't try anything... i took this code from other website.. script is not working.. but i found that they are randomly changing class, other animations are loading from css..

Comment: mate, this is not a coding service. Try from your end and shoot the issues here please!

Comment: @NidhinJoseph: Someone will be interested to help me out.. So thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will rotate the classes through each `li` element which has a `card*` class. It gets the current class, increments the number (modulo 5) and then applies it to the element.

```js
var step = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  $('li[class^="card"]').each(function() {
     let thisclass = $(this).attr('class');
     let num = (1 + parseInt(thisclass.slice(-1))) % 5;
     let nextclass = 'card' + num;
     $(this).removeClass(thisclass).addClass(nextclass);
     });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.card0 { background-color: red; }
.card1 { background-color: blue; }
.card2 { background-color: green; }
.card3 { background-color: yellow; }
.card4 { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changelog">

  <ul class="entries">
    <li class="card0">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>August  1</span>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card1">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Terminal</strong>
        <span>July 30</span>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card2">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>July 29</span>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card3">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Radar</strong>
        <span>July 22</span>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card4">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Mobile</strong>
        <span>July 19</span>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `setInterval` check the snippet.

```js
var step = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (step > 5) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    return false;
  }
  $('.entries li').addClass('card' + step);
  step++;

}, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changelog">

  <ul class="entries">
    <li class="card0" style="transform: translateY(122px) scale(1.07);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>August  1</span>
      </p>
      <p>Platforms can now export connected account information as a CSV from the Dashboard.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card1" style="transform: translateY(152px) scale(1);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Terminal</strong>
        <span>July 30</span>
      </p>
      <p>You can now use WiFi to connect a P400 card reader to your point of sale application.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card2" style="transform: translateY(182px) scale(0.934579);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>July 29</span>
      </p>
      <p>Express accounts now support 5 new languages (German, Italian, Japanese, Spanish, and Simplified Chinese) for the onboarding flow, dashboard, emails, and text messages.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card3" style="transform: translateY(212px) scale(0.873439);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Radar</strong>
        <span>July 22</span>
      </p>
      <p>Set rules with the new <code>is_off_session</code> attribute, which detects if a customer was charged anytime after they initially completed the checkout&nbsp;flow.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card4" style="transform: translateY(272px) scale(0.816298);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Mobile</strong>
        <span>July 19</span>
      </p>
      <p>Our updated mobile SDKs now support in-app 3D Secure 2 authentication, letting you customize the appearance of the authentication&nbsp;UI.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No its not interchanging the class... this code is just keep on adding the class

Comment: <li class="card1 card0 card2 card3 card4"> like this its adding

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the `li` elements and increment their class.

Try the snippet below:

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("entries");
var li = ul[0].children;

function increment(num) {
  if( (num + 1) > (li.length - 1) )
    return 0;
  return num + 1;
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  for(var i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var num = li[i].classList[0].substr(4);
    li[i].removeAttribute("class");
    li[i].setAttribute( "class", "card" + increment(parseInt(num)) );
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="changelog">
  <ul class="entries">
    <li class="card0" style="transform: translateY(122px) scale(1.07);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>August  1</span>
      </p>
      <p>Platforms can now export connected account information as a CSV from the Dashboard.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card1" style="transform: translateY(152px) scale(1);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Terminal</strong>
        <span>July 30</span>
      </p>
      <p>You can now use WiFi to connect a P400 card reader to your point of sale application.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card2" style="transform: translateY(182px) scale(0.934579);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Connect</strong>
        <span>July 29</span>
      </p>
      <p>Express accounts now support 5 new languages (German, Italian, Japanese, Spanish, and Simplified Chinese) for the onboarding flow, dashboard, emails, and text messages.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card3" style="transform: translateY(212px) scale(0.873439);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Radar</strong>
        <span>July 22</span>
      </p>
      <p>Set rules with the new <code>is_off_session</code> attribute, which detects if a customer was charged anytime after they initially completed the checkout&nbsp;flow.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="card4" style="transform: translateY(272px) scale(0.816298);">
      <p class="meta">
        <strong>Mobile</strong>
        <span>July 19</span>
      </p>
      <p>Our updated mobile SDKs now support in-app 3D Secure 2 authentication, letting you customize the appearance of the authentication&nbsp;UI.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```